# Spring Boot fetch user role from DB using LDAP login

Tags: spring, ldap

I could login via LDAP but I cant fetch user role which is stored in my Database. I do get the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl cannot be cast to com.test.rnd.geo.web.dto.CustomUser
```

```
    private CustomUser getUserDetails() {
        CustomUser userDetails = (CustomUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        LOGGER.info("Deatils:  "+userDetails);
        LOGGER.info("UserName: " + userDetails.getUsername());
        LOGGER.info("Auth Token: " + userDetails.getAuthToken());
        LOGGER.info("User Role size: " + userDetails.getAuthorities().size());
        LOGGER.info("User Role : " + userDetails.getAuthorities());


        return userDetails;
    }
```

I am getting error to fetch this getUserDetails() function.

```
        CustomUser customUser = getUserDetails();
            String role = customUser.getAuthorities().stream().findFirst().get().getAuthority();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use a userDetailsContextMapper() and mapUserFromContext() functions. Where you could authenticate your custom user and then return the CustomUser object.